# What is the best way to handle dynamic subdomains in golang with gin router

Tags: go, go-gin

Hello Everyone,

I am working on a project where I need to setup the multiple sub-domains with the routes. I tried code with two sub-domains, but in my case it would be 100 sub-domains. I tried the following code for this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type Subdomains map[string]http.Handler

func (subdomains Subdomains) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    domainParts := strings.Split(r.Host, ".")

    if mux := subdomains[domainParts[0]]; mux != nil {
        mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Not found", 404)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r2 := gin.Default()
    hs := make(Subdomains)
    hs["admin"] = r
    hs["analytics"] = r2
    r.GET("/ping", adminHandlerOne)
    r2.GET("/ping", adminHandlerOne)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", hs)
}
func adminHandlerOne(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "pong",
    })
}
```

But I think that this is not good. Is anybody know the proper way to do this?

Comment: did you test your code ?

Comment: @YandryPozo Hello Yes my code working fine for me. you can test with urls. http://admin.localhost:9090/ping, http://analytics.localhost:9090/ping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`*httputil.ReverseProxy`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) for this. Here is how I would reroute to a subdomain based on a hostname without any middleware in Gin.

```
router.GET("/:username", func(c *gin.Context) {
    uri, ok := c.Get("location")
    if !ok {
        c.JSON(500, gin.H{
            "reason": "Location unknown",
        })
    }
    hostname := "awesome.io"
    if uri.(*url.URL).Host == hostname {
        // Want to send client to "https://auth.awesome.io/:username"
        s := fmt.Sprintf("https://auth.%s/%s", domain, c.Param("username"))
        uri, err := url.Parse(s)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(500, gin.H{
                "reason": "Subdomain is wrong",
            })
        }
        rp := new(httputil.ReverseProxy)

        // Modify request's URL to point to the new uri
        rp.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
            req.URL = uri
        }
        rp.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Pie for your answer but this post was old and I have already implemented a solution for this.

Comment: Don't worry. This is for future benefits to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a subdomainHandler type that implements http.Handler interface
type subdomainHandler struct {
    routers map[string]*gin.Engine // a map of routers for each subdomain
}

// Implement the ServeHTTP method for subdomainHandler
func (s *subdomainHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Get the subdomain from the Host header
    host := r.Host
    subdomain := strings.Split(host, ".")[0]
    // Check if there is a router for the subdomain
    if router, ok := s.routers[subdomain]; ok {
        // Use the router to handle the request
        router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    } else {
        // No router found, return an error
        http.Error(w, "Not found", 404)
    }
}

// Create a newSubdomainHandler function that returns a new subdomainHandler with the given routers
func newSubdomainHandler(routers map[string]*gin.Engine) *subdomainHandler {
    return &subdomainHandler{routers: routers}
}

// In the main function, create different routers for each subdomain and pass them to the newSubdomainHandler function
func main() {
    // Create a router for the main domain
    mainRouter := gin.Default()
    mainRouter.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "Welcome to the main domain")
    })

    // Create a router for the admin subdomain
    adminRouter := gin.Default()
    adminRouter.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "Welcome to the admin subdomain")
    })

    // Create a router for the blog subdomain
    blogRouter := gin.Default()
    blogRouter.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "Welcome to the blog subdomain")
    })

    // Create a map of routers for each subdomain
    routers := map[string]*gin.Engine{
        "":      mainRouter,
        "admin": adminRouter,
        "blog":  blogRouter,
    }

    handler := newSubdomainHandler(routers)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options (write a router, write wrappers, attempt to bend gin to your will), but as the default ServeMux supports this, and you probably really don't need gin in particular, I'd go with the standard router. Take a look at the source of the [DefaultServeMux](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=69186:69230#L2066) first, to get an idea of how simple a router is at heart - a router is just a map of paths to handlers.

The Default [ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) actually does what you want (allows matching on host as well as path), so I'd suggest trying with that first. Register your patterns:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", handlerRoot)
mux.HandleFunc("analytics.example.com/", handlerOne)
mux.HandleFunc("admin.example.com/", handlerTwo)
err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", mux)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Write some handlers (obviously you might write json with an encoder rather than directly, this is just an example):

```
func handlerOne(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := fmt.Sprintf(`{"one":"%s"}`, r.Host)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(j))
}
```

If you're then testing this on localhost, you'd probably want to edit your /etc/hosts file to be sure you hit the server with the right hostname.

Putting that together, you could use something like this to test with:

https://play.golang.org/p/ut-GT_s3Gf

Note these subdomains could be dynamic if you want (the mention of 100 plus makes me think they might be), and you could just customise behaviour at runtime in handlers rather than using separate handlers, it depends how differently the domains behave.

Comment: Thanks @Kenny Grant for your answer. I checked the Default ServeMux and your code. It works fine, but I have completed my app with the  gin router now I need to implement the sub-domain part using the gin. Can you please provide a way to complete this with gin.

Comment: Sorry, don’t use gin. Does it support domains? If so do something similar?

Comment: @KennyGrant I'm implementing something similar to the OP. I'm using ServeMux like you recommended, Thanks! How would you make the subdomains dynamic to support hundreds of them?